# C Convert string to integer using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

I'm making a program where user enters grades (1 to 5) and then the grade gets added to array for later inspection. When user enters letter "s", the program closes. When ran my program crashes, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;
int grade[50];
char *num[20];

int enter();
int enter()
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

        printf("\nEnter grade:\nPress [s] to close program\n");
        scanf("%s",&num[i]);
        if (strcmp(num[i],"s") == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            grade[i] = atoi(num[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    enter();

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("\n%d",grade[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: read char array and strings in C again.

Comment: Why not make array of integers? And you should initialize the array because you print the 10 values regardless if they are added in the enter method

Comment: What if the user (we can't trust users, can we????) enters "S" or "q" or "exit"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

remove  ' * '  from num[20] declaration, as you are declaring 20 character string pointers, so reading and comparing values with num[i] will cause error.
Besides, you just nead a simple string to get the grade.

Comment: removing '*' will just cause warning:  [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Answer (score 0):

The reason why program crashed is that `num` is a pointer array, the element of `num` can not pointer to valid memory which used to store the string you inputed.
you can change `char *num[10]` to `char num[10][12]` and 'scanf("%s", &num[i])`to scanf("%s", num[i])`, and that everything will be OK.

Of course, you can use `malloc` to dynamic alloc memory for each element in `num`, like:

```
`for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
     num[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
  }
`
```

Even thought, you must change `scanf("%s", &num[i])` to `scanf("%s", num[i])`;
Finally, you can not forget to free the memory you just dynamic malloc.